# {again} C# MessageBox created more than once

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, messagebox

I have a similar question as last time, but no matter how much I hit my head against the wall, solution is not coming. The problem is that the message box gets created too many times, when it should only open once, unsubscribe from `documentCompleted` and then exit. Thanks again!

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox4.Text.Length >= 3)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox4.Text != "")
    {
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-gb/search?q=" + textBox4.Text);

        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += GetImg; //sub here
    }
}

private void GetImg(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string img_url = "";
    foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
    {
        if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "Avatar-image")
        {
            img_url = (el.OuterHtml).Substring(el.OuterHtml.IndexOf("https"));
            img_url = img_url.Substring(0, img_url.IndexOf(")"));
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = img_url;
        }
        else if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "Character-level")
        {
            textBox5.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            string lvl_url = "";
            lvl_url = (el.InnerHtml).Substring(3);
            lvl_url = lvl_url.Substring(0, lvl_url.IndexOf("<"));
            textBox5.Text = lvl_url;
            DialogResult YESNO = MessageBox.Show("Is this your character?", "Select your char", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (YESNO == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                // clean up
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= GetImg; //unsub here
                pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
                timer1.Dispose();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either set timer1.Enabled to false or call timer1.Stop() as soon as you enter the timer1_Tick_1 method, or the timer will keep firing and calling your method every time.

Comment: You my friend are a genius :). Care to explain why this is happening?

Comment: Sure, basically, when you Start() or Enable a timer, the timer fires forever until you choose to stop it. I see that you are using "Dispose" in your GetImg method, but, GetImg will only be called on DocumentCompleted (which could happen a lot of time after you started the download) and the timer can fire multiple times in between (thus calling your timer1_Tick_1 method multiple times). Did that help?